# Loyal ubuntu member

Tags: discussion

I have been using Ubuntu sense Ubuntu 6 .I was a helping member of the first Ubuntu.
com . I have been a member here sense day one and now i have to get 50 points before i can reply to help some one .What,s the go ?

Comment: -1 Based on your profile:   member for  1 year, 11 months | This user has not participated in any tags | This user has not earned any badges | This user has not answered any questions.

Comment: Maybe if you look a little harder you may find a lot more .

Comment: Why i am asking .it looks like i have been hacked .post not where they should be .

Comment: You could try looking for user asux or asux1 or ckasux .or do you forget all the time,s we had to re register sit crash lost info .

Comment: Never had any issue with login and never had  to make new user profiles. user asux exist for 1 year and  3 months but no any activity, user asux1 or ckasux not in database. If I could i would give you another -1

Comment: i should be in ubuntu testing as well .o well it must be government whipping my info out .lol thanks anyway

Answer (score 6):

The [privileges on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/) are all based around your experience with Ask Ubuntu. It's "gamification" to:

- Protect us from people who would abuse things (spam et al)
- Ensure that you know what features are actually for (over-use of links, comments, images, etc)
- Reward users who stick with it.

It's not all frowns though because being a long-term Ubuntu, you should find it easier to answer questions which should mean you progress faster than your comrades.

Comment: maybe someone could link all my user names back to one .

Comment: Yeah that's possible… Just click the contact link in the footer.